# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. from mobile services

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I created a simple vanilla ToDo from azure mobile template to test the service but don't seem to work correctly.  I can connect to https://phonegapwil.azure-mobile.net from localhost with mobile services but not after I published site, http://phonegapwil.azurewebsites.net/

error message I get:
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load  https://phonegapwil.azure-mobile.net/tables/todoitem?$filter=(complete%20eq%20false). No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://phonegapwil.azurewebsites.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I also tried "*" for the CORS but no go.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a CORS related issue, you put '*' in the portal config for your mobile service? Can you try listing your website name instead?

Comment: I just browsed to your published site (`http://phonegapwil.azurewebsites.net/`) and it was able to retrieve data from the mobile service (it shows the data from the table). Have you been able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply @phillipv.  I used "*" but still didn't work.  I used .net as my mobile service back-end and that was the problem.  Seems like they have a bug.  I recreated this using node back-end and worked without an issue.

come on Microsoft

I saw a nuget fix here
[cors not working with azure mobile service .net backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488470/cors-not-working-with-azure-mobile-service-net-backend)